# How to apply responsive design in Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Can anyone suggest , how I can apply bootstrap for displaying maximum 4 divs in desktop, 3 in tablet and 1 in mobile device.

Add divs dynamically :

Condition : 
1. Desktop (Maximum 4 divs in a row):
For desktop if 1 div will be there , it should be in center position and it should cover the window width(100%).If 2 divs ,window width should be (50% and 50%).If 3 divs , window width should be(33%,33% and 33%). Similarly if 4 will be added ,window width should cover(25%,25%,25%, and 25%).

How can i do it in Angular.js ?

I have applied bootstrap for the div.Code snippet here,Please suggest

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
```

Comment: `col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-12`

Comment: Its not working. For desktop ,if only 1 div is there then 1 div should cover the width of window screen. If 2 div will be there , 2 div should cover the window screen.If 3 div will be there , 3 div should cover the window screen. Similarly if 4 div is there, it should cover the desktop screen. Maximum of 4 div is there .

Comment: You have to code it accordingly - why don't you have a go, post your code and then we can help if you get stuck

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
```

You can check the documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Its not working. For desktop ,if only 1 div is there then 1 div should cover the width of window screen. If 2 div will be there , 2 div should cover the window screen.If 3 div will be there , 3 div should cover the window screen. Similarly if 4 div is there, it should cover the desktop screen. Maximum of 4 div is there .

Comment: you need to use js or jquery to do this

Comment: How can i do it in Angular.js ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
           <p>dhcsdh</p>
         </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
           <p>dhcsdh</p>
         </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
           <p>dhcsdh</p>
         </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
           <p>dhcsdh</p>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```